# local tomcat with eclipse attempt to run jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-inf

I have local tomcat running. 
I have eclipse loading contexts to this tomcat instance.

I have a jsp under webappl, which I redirect to in servlet, and which I can access at :8080/mywebapp/my.jsp.

If I create a directory under webappl/alljsps , and move my.jsp to this location webappl/alljsps/my.jsp, I can not redirect, and I can not access at :8080/mywebapp/alljsps/my.jsp.

What steps are required to access this moved jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access jsps under WEB-INF if you redirect to them through a servlet. Nothing on WEB-INF can be accessed directly.

Comment: Just did..No servlet required.:8080/mywebapp/my.jsp. is aok.

Comment: Check if you dont have a copy of your jsp under the app directory.

Comment: @Paul Anything under WEB-INF is hidden by default from being served to a web request. You must have some kind of configuration error (Or another copy of the jsp in your app directory as Andres says)

Comment: It is eclipse with contexts and tomcat local. More important, so redirect to alljsps/my.jsp(doesn't work) vs /my.jsp (WORKS). What steps to follow eclipse/tomcat testing so dispatcher.forward will work? Change eclipse, tomcat, config?

Comment: It was not WEB_INF, it is just a another sub under webappl. Tis Friday.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve it with a Servlet, the container will not serve JSP files under WEB-INF directly (that's usually the point). Instead, you would usually use a [`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) to [`include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) it.